# setting directory path for picture on php

Tags: php

I'm setting paths for some pictures. Here is my problem

```
<?php
/*C:\xampp\htdocs\test\online_catalog\pictures-1\sloth-1.jpg */ directory 1
echo "<img src='pictures-1/sloth-1.jpg' />";

echo "<hr/>";



 /* C:\xampp\htdocs\test\online_catalog\New folder\pictures-2\sloth-2.jpg */ directory 2
echo "<img src='../pictures-2/sloth-2.jpg'  />";
?>
```

I saved the file as animal.php. It's location is `C:\xampp\htdocs\test\online_catalog\animal.php`

the first link works normally but the second one is not works. Did i set wrong path ?

Comment: you forgot `New Folder` in the 2nd image's path.

Comment: `../` is moving one folder _up_ – you want to go the other way, _down_ into the folder `New folder`. (Which is not a good name, you should try avoiding spaces in HTTP paths – and if you have to use them, then at least URL-encode those special characters properly.)

Comment: and "New Folder" has a space that will need escaping (if you really *want* to use that name)

Answer (score 1):

The path for the second image should be:

```
echo '<img src="New%20folder\pictures-2\sloth-2.jpg" />';
```